# Appcompat 1.0.0 issue

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, androidx

I am new in IntelliJ, and I am trying to automate testing on mobile app. When I run my code, I keep facing build.gradle issue. Here is the code

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29+'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat.appcompat:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    //implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1")
   //implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')

}
if(hasProperty('buildScan')){
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service';
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}
```

and the error is 
[image]

How do I ensure rock-solidly that build.gradle is all compatible ?

Comment: Check the typo in the dependency. Use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0` instead of `androidx.appcompat.appcompat:1.0.0`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, thanks. After doing your recommended steps, it's seems to compile promisingly. This is a positive step. However, at the end, the same error still turn up. Funny thing is, even after I edit as per your advice, the error message still mentioned that I am typing the typo. But big thanks for your help. Would appreciate too if you could advise me on the latest error.